# Understand javascript function declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that $ is an alias to jQuery. Below code is passing an anonymous function to the $ function which can take a callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Perfect. It is simple and clear. But in one of the website I see below two files but could not understand what is it doing.

**File 1**

```
(function($, window, document, ns) {
    "use strict";
    ...
    ...
})
($, window, document, Granite.author);
```

**File 2**

```
(function($,document) {
    "use strict";
    ...
    ...
})(Granite.$, document);
```

Can anyone help me to understand what we are passing $, window, document, ns etc?

Comment: this will help you understand approximately - https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/what-function-window-document-undefined-iife-really-means. "use strict" - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: Its a module pattern to try to keep from leaking globals and explicitly inject dependencies.

Comment: Thank you  s.kuznetsov. It really helped to understand the concept

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a jQuery concept. It is creating a function and calling it immediatly.

Something like this:

```js
(function (argument) { 
    console.log(argument) 
})("This is being passed to the function")
```

Another way to do it using arrow functions would be

```js
((argument) => { console.log(argument) })("This is being passed to the arrow function")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Small query. if we are not using the argument inside the function then argument is not necessary in the code right ? for example in my File1, there are not using window, document, ns but there are using $ (jquery) which means it is not used window, document, ns not used in file and can be removed isn't ? Will it(window, document, ns) be used outside of this function ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want a function that calling itself, you can define it between

```
(function hello(){
    console.log("hello")
})()
```

This will automatically call the function and log the "hello".